# deleting '\n' from a subprocess.Popen result in python

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I'm trying to save ('ls -l') results in a variable using subprocess.Popen,
my problem is when I print the array it has '\n' for every element.

this is my code

```
result = subprocess.Popen("ls -1 | sed -e 's/\..*$//'", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
variables = result.stdout.readlines()
```

I can't use strip() since variables is not a list.

is there any way to remove those `'\n'` ?

Comment: `readlines()` **does** return a list, you can `map` over every element calling `strip`

Comment: so how should i do it ?

Comment: `map(str.strip,variables)`?